# How to read that sum?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

My exercise is to show that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{N+n \choose n}z^{n} =1/(1-z)^{N+1}$ where $N\in\{0,1,2,\ldots\}$ and
$z\in\mathbb{C}$ with $\lvert z \rvert <1$.

Now, this doesn't even work with $z=0+0i=0$.
So I'm done here or what?

Or does the sum gets multiplied by $z^{n}$ and its not part of the sum?

A hint to that is the "Cauchy-product" of series.

Comment: For $z=0$, you have the LHS being equal to $\binom{N+0}{0} z^0 = 1\cdot 1 = 1$, with the usual convention that $0^0=1$. So it does "work."

Comment: ah thanks... i forgot that, since my calculator says error to 0^0.

Comment: Did you try an induction in $N$? To use the Cauchy product is a very good hint.

Comment: It certainly does work for $z=0$ with the usual convention that $0^0=1$ when the only non-zero term in the summation is $\binom {N}{0}0^0=1$ and the RHS is equal to $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)), or consider that:

$$\begin{eqnarray*}(1-z)^{N+1}\sum_{n\geq 0}\binom{N+n}{n}z^n &=& \left(\sum_{k=0}^{N+1}\binom{N+1}{k}(-1)^k z^k\right)\left(\sum_{n\geq 0}\binom{N+n}{n}z^n\right)\\&=&\sum_{m\geq 0}z^m\sum_{k=0}^{m}\binom{N+k}{m-k}\binom{N+1}{k}(-1)^{k}\end{eqnarray*}$$
involves a trivial [binomial transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_transform): the only non-zero coefficient of the last Taylor series is the one for $m=0$, that equals $1$. As an alternative, recall that:
$$\sum_{k=n}^{N}\binom{k}{n}=\binom{N+1}{n+1},\tag{1} $$
and that if 
$$ f(z) = \sum_{n\geq 0} a_n z^n, $$
then:
$$ \frac{f(z)}{1-z} = \sum_{n\geq 0} A_n z^n,\qquad A_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_n.\tag{2}$$
If the radius of convergence of the Taylor series of $f(z)$ at $z=0$ is $1$, the same holds for $\frac{f(z)}{1-z}$.

You may also use the integral representation of the factorials:
$$\begin{eqnarray*}\sum_{n\geq 0}\binom{N+n}{n}z^n = \frac{1}{N!}\sum_{n\geq 0}(N+n)!\frac{z^n}{n!}&=&\frac{1}{N!}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\sum_{n\geq 0}t^{N+n}e^{-t}\frac{z^n}{n!}\,dt\\&=&\frac{1}{N!}\int_{0}^{+\infty} t^N e^{tz}e^{-t}\,dt\\&=&\frac{1}{N!(1-z)^{N+1}}\int_{0}^{+\infty}u^N e^{-u}\,du\\&=&\frac{1}{(1-z)^{N+1}}.\tag{3}\end{eqnarray*}$$

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Leftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> With the *well known identity* [( see expression $\pars{5}$ in this link )](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinomialCoefficient.html)
>
> $\ds{{N + n \choose n} = {-\bracks{N + n} + n - 1 \choose n}\pars{1}^{n} =
> {-N - 1 \choose n}\pars{-1}^{n}}$:

\begin{align}
\color{#f00}{\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{N + n \choose n}z^{n}} & =
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{-N - 1 \choose n}\pars{-z}^{n} =
\bracks{1 + \pars{-z}}^{\ -N - 1} =
\color{#f00}{1 \over \pars{1 - z}^{N+1}}
\end{align}